# Input something about each entry on a list in python 3

Tags: python

i just began playing with python 3 and got a little stuck. I have this code:

```
person = ['George', 'Andrew', 'Ryan', 'Jack', 'Daniel']
for item in person:
        opinion = input("What do you think about "+person[0]+"? ")
        print(person[0]+" is a "+opinion+"")
```

And i do not know how to make it ask about each of the persons in the list. I know person[0] is not good, but i do not know what to put there.

EDIT:

I tried fixing it with a loop:

```
person = ['George', 'Andrew', 'Ryan', 'Jack', 'Daniel']
i = 0
while i<5:
    opinion = input("What do you think about "+person[i]+"? ")
    print(person[i]+" is a "+opinion+"")
    i += 1
```

And it works, but after it runs out of people on the list and i keep replying, i get an error. There has to be a better way

Comment: You are already looping over the list.  Why are you using `person[0]` instead of `item`?

Comment: You should take a look at the docs: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements

Comment: `for item in person` assigns each element of `person` to `item` in a loop.

Comment: _"after it runs out of people on the list and i keep replying, i get an error."_ Works fine on my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that when you are running your `for` loop, `item` will be whichever person you have in question. Thus, replace `person[0]` with `item` and you will ask about each person as required, like so:

```
for item in person:
        opinion = input("What do you think about "+item+"? ")
        print(item+" is a "+opinion+"")
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning `item` to each value in `person`, use that variable.

```
for item in person:
        opinion = input("What do you think about "+item+"? ")
        print(item+" is a "+opinion+"")
```

When you called `person[0]`, you were setting it to the first value in `person` **every time**, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
for item in person
    opinion = input("What do you think about "+item+"? ")
    print(item+" is a "+opinion+"")
```

And even better, if you want to make it more verbose:

```
# List with "s" to make it plural
persons = ['George', 'Andrew', 'Ryan', 'Jack', 'Daniel']

# List item without the "s"
for person in persons
    opinion = input("What do you think about " + person + "? ")
    print(person + " is a " + opinion + "")
```